# Why I cannot include AppKit in pure C, even though I can declare the functions myself?

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I would like to write a MacOS application using more C and less ObjC and Swift. I started by creating a `main.c` file with the `main` function. Next is to call `NSApplicationMain` from the `main` function. This is defined in AppKit. However, I get a `Could not build module 'AppKit'` error when I try `#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>` from `main.c`. I circumvented this with:

```
extern int NSApplicationMain(int argc, const char * _Nonnull *argv);
```

This worked. My question is, clearly `NSApplicationMain` can be called from C so why do I *have* to extern it directly instead of including `AppKit.h` directly? Why they do not let you include it the proper way instead of declaring `NSApplicationMain` yourself? Am I not supposed to do that?

Why can you not do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

But you *can* do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int NSApplicationMain(int argc, const char * _Nonnull *argv);
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: sounds like AppKit/AppKit.h may not be a C header.  #include pretty much grabs the text from a file and plops it there.  Also sounds like you can just make your own header with those extern declarations from your mention of what worked.

Comment: @Abel I believe `AppKit/AppKit.h` is an Objective-C header, but if I can use the functions anyway in pure C, why do they keep you from just using the header?

Comment: because it is an Objective C header.  "They" may have a pure C header somewhere else.  If not, you can always make one.  If most people don't use it your way, "they" may simply lack motivation to create the other headers you would need.

Comment: @Abel But if there are C compatible functions in an Objective C header, why do they keep you from including it? There should be like `#ifdef __OBJC__` for all the non C compatible functions like the ones that deal in `NSObject`s, but alas, they did not do it, so I need to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it is not standard C header file though it has `.h` extension. Note, that even in Objective-C `.m` files `AppKit.h` must be imported not included

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an authority on this, but my take would be: AppKit is an Objective-C framework.  It therefore has a header file that is written in Objective-C, and that can't be included in C.  When you declare an AppKit function in C and call it, you are basically relying on the fact that the ABI – the internal calling conventions of registers, stack usage, etc. – are the same between both languages, and so it works (and I'm not actually certain that the ABI *is* 100% the same, although I *think* it is); but technically, you are calling an Objective-C function from C.  There's no particular reason why Apple ought to bend over backwards to make that easy; programming in pure C is not common any more.  If you really want to do this, you could always just make your C source file be a .m (Objective-C) file but limit yourself to only pure C language features.  That will let you include the header, while letting you write "C" code (actually Objective-C, limited to the C subset of the language).  Seems like a good solution to me.